# Debug macro for C++ with variable arguments without the format string

Tags: c++, debugging, macros, variadic-functions

Is it possible to write a macro which can take in a variable number of arguments and expands like this :

```
quickdebug(a)   ->  cout << #a ": " << a;
quickdebug(a,b) ->  cout << #a ": " << a << #b ": "<< b;
```

etc

If not, is it possible for me to at least print all the arguments without giving format strings. e.g

```
quickdebug2(a)   -> cout << a ;
quickdebug2(a,b) -> cout << a << " " << b ;
```

etc

For example in java I can write a function which provides me similar functionality:

```
void debug(Object...args) 
{
  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(args));
}
```

Comment: In Java you cannot do `#a`. So the analogy is incorrect. You can accomplish what you did in Java with variadic templates in C++ (or multiple non variadic templates).

Comment: What I did in Java is an analogy for quickdebug2. And using variadic templates, I dont understand how can I find out the size & type of arguments. I mean I wish to be able to use it like this as well(which I can do in Java) : debug(42, "inner", 23.2)

Comment: "using variadic templates, I dont understand how can I find out the size & type of arguments" Heh? That's what variadic templates are for.

Comment: An example of this is the [`printf` variadic template in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_Templates). Your version would go something like this: `void quickdebug() { } template<typename A, typename... B> void quickdebug(A a, B... b) { std::cout << a; quickdebug(b...); }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using a class that overrides , operator:

```
class VariadicToOutputStream
{
public:
    VariadicToOutputStream(std::ostream& s, const std::string& separator = " ") : m_stream(s), m_hasEntries(false), m_separator(separator) {}
    template<typename ObjectType>
    VariadicToOutputStream& operator , (const ObjectType& v)
    {
        if (m_hasEntries) m_stream << m_separator;
        m_stream << v;
        m_hasEntries=true;
        return *this;
    }
    ~VariadicToOutputStream()
    {
        m_stream << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::ostream& m_stream;
    bool m_hasEntries;
    std::string m_separator;
};
```

You can write for instance:

```
VariadicToOutputStream(std::cout) , 1, 0.5f, "a string";
```

This can then be wrapped with a preprocessor macro:

```
#define VARIADIC_TO_STDOUT(...)     VariadicToOutputStream(std::cout),__VA_ARGS__;
```

So you can write:

```
VARIADIC_TO_STDOUT(1, 0.5f, "a string");
```

It would be easy to add f.i. separator strings to be used between arguments.

Edit: I just added a default space as separator string.

Comment: Thanks Robert, for the magic. This is probably the coolest C++ hack I've ever seen. Hail! :)

Comment: I've made a small change : I've created a destructor for this class that prints a new line. So every macro call when returns prints a new line in the end. If you wish so, you might edit it in your answer as well =)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to make a macro that is variadic thus taking a variable amount of arguments. The syntax is similar to that of a function:

```
#define quickdebug(...) functiontocall("test", __VA_ARGS__)
```

Any argument listed after the last named argument in the argument list will be listed in `__VA_ARGS__` including any seperating comma.

So: `quickdebug(1, 2, "123", 4.5)` becomes `functioncall("test", 1, 2 , "123", 4.5)`

However at some point you need to use these arguments, and here it can become extremely difficult if you don't have a format string, or something else indicating the type of the arguments.

The problem is that when reading variables from a variable arguments list, you need to know the type of the argument, or at least its size. If I were you I would choose a different approach.

You can read more about variadic macros here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html